# If $F(x)$ is onto function such that $F: \mathbb R \to [-1,2]$ , $F(x)= \frac {x^2+9bx+17}{ax^3+x^2+bx+33}$ and $F'(d)=F'(e)=0$ where $d<e$ then

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functions

The following question appeared in entrance and i din't solve it because i thought it will take lot of time.Is there any "smart" way to solve this?

> If $F(x)$ is onto function such that $F: \mathbb R \to [-1,2]$ , $F(x)= \frac {x^2+9bx+17}{ax^3+x^2+bx+33}$ and $F'(d)=F'(e)=0$ where $d<e$ then

$(1)a+b+d+e=4$
$(2)a+b+d+e=-4$
$(3) d+e=2$
$(4) d+e=-2$

More than one options can also be correct.Any hints/ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $F'(d) = F'(e) = 0$ gives you two equations.

Surjectivity allows you to assert that $F(x) = 2$ for some $x$, and $F(x) = -1$ for some $x$, and any other real number between $-1$ and $2$. This gives you some more information. Just calculate the derivative and insert the points. The result should fall out easily.

Comment: It may work but derivative is itself $4$th degree polynomial so i don't think it will be easy to work with that.

Comment: Hmmm I think you have to...

Answer (score -1):

$a$ must be  zero given that the function is defined for all real.

Moreover subjectivity can be used to determine value of $b$ along with definition of the function.
Then proceed to find $d$ and $e$ with the so formed quadratic expression.

Answer (score -1):

answers a and c
given that $f(x)$ lies between $-1$ and $2$
on applying that condition we must solve the inequalities
$$x^2+9bx+17/ax^3+x^2+bx+33$$
is greter than $-1$
$$ \implies -(ax^3 + x^2 + bx + 33) \le x^2 + 9bx +17$$
$$ \implies ax^3 + 2x^2 + 10bx + 50 \ge 0 $$
($x$ belongs to R, because range is $-1$ to $2$ for all $x$)
a cubic always goes from $-\infty$ to $+ \infty$.... but we have to find a cubic equation which is always positive which is not possible, therefore value of $a=0$
$2x^2 + 10bx + 50 \ge 0$ if we keep $b=2$ we get a perfect square which is always +ve
now solve $f(x) \le2$ even here you get a quadratic in which $b=2$ condition satisfies the inequality..........now we need to find $d$ and $e$...........now we have $a$ and $b$ values..........$d$ and $e$ are local extremes of the function we get local maximum when function value is $2$ and local minimum when function value is $-1$
on solving we gwt $d=-5$ and $e=7$
so $a+ b+ d+ e=4$
and $d + e =2$

Comment: This is illegible. Please revise this post using MathJax and indentations.

Comment: Use MathJax to render the math. You have a quick refrence and tutorial here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference